# Display error message daily

Tags: 7, commerce

Is there a way to display error message daily to the user saying that "Your subscription Expiry in x days". And this message needs to popup each and everyday.

I can use `hook_init()`(this will run each and every page load), is there any other hook/option available?

Comment: _this will run each and every page load_ Not true, it won't run for cached pages

Comment: Agreed Clive, Thanks for info. I only have anon cache. But this messages are ment only for authenticated user. Thats my intention

Comment: Are you interested in a solution that requires a contributed module?

Comment: I would love to give a try on that, if it is heavy at least i will reuse/utilize the code.

Comment: Hey @Nagarjuna , I forgot about this question from before, sorry. Extra question (before posting an answer): can you think of a way to create a view that has 1 row for each subscription that is not expired yet, and this for the logged in user? FYI: it doesn't matter which data (columns) such view would actually show in each row, all I'd need (to make what I'm thinking of work) is a view with 1 row for each not expired subscription. Let me know!

Answer (score 0):

hook_init is used, when you want to do something while the request is initialized, 
you could use ***hook_preprocess_page*** and there set the message, checking on a custom field you added to your user, storing the date of the last information. If this is not today, then show it and update the field value.